# Autostart minecraft server

Tags: server, java, minecraft

Hi how can make this sh script runs after boot? I tried this but it doesn't work.

***/etc/systemd/system/my-startup.service***

```
[Unit]
Description=Start Minecraft
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/home/dre/minecraft/start.sh
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

***/home/dre/minecraft/start.sh***

```
#!/bin/bash
screen -d -m java -Xmx3990M -Xms3990M -jar server.jar nogui
```

***systemctl status my-startup.sh***

```
● my-startup.service - Start Minecraft
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/my-startup.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2021-01-11 00:50:09 UTC; 10min ago
   Main PID: 625 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 11 00:50:09 optiplex systemd[1]: Started Start Minecraft.
Jan 11 00:50:09 optiplex systemd[1]: my-startup.service: Succeeded.
```

But there's nothing in ***screen -ls*** and server hasn't turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are problems with your .service file.

1. You are running the script as root. Bad Idea. You should run as a non-root user, in case your server gets compromised. Add a `User=<username>` line to the `[Service]` section.
2. Use the .service file to trigger `screen` directly using the `ExecStart=` line. That way you can use systemd the way it's intended as a tool to start, stop, restart, and monitor the Minecraft server.

Here's an example from my own Minecraft server....

```
[Service]
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/minecraft
User=minecraft
# Start Screen, Java, and Minecraft
ExecStart=screen -s mc -d -m java -server -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -jar server.jar nogui
# Tell Minecraft to gracefully stop.
# Ending Minecraft will terminate Java
# systemd will kill Screen after the 10-second delay. No explicit kill for Screen needed
ExecStop=screen -p 0 -S mc -X eval 'stuff "say SERVER SHUTTING DOWN. Saving map..."\015'
ExecStop=screen -p 0 -S mc -X eval 'stuff "save-all"\015'
ExecStop=screen -p 0 -S mc -X eval 'stuff "stop"\015'
ExecStop=sleep 10
```

Comment: Thank you, working!